# How do I generate a sparse invertible 10000 by 10000 binary matrix with 30 to 50 non-zeros per row?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

How do I generate a sparse invertible 10000 by 10000 binary matrix with 30 to 50 non-zeros per row(uniform distribution)?

What sort of algorithm should I use to do this task?

**Brute Force algorithm-
Using a random generator, create a such a matrix, and test for invertibility by finding its determinant/Gaussian Elimination.**

(I tried this approach, the algorithm never completes within 1 hour, so I gaved up)

**Reverse ERO approach-
Starting with an identity matrix, do repeated Elementary Row Operations on it until the above is fulfiled.**

(I haven't tried this approach yet, it is possible that it will work, but there is simply no way to guarantee that every row will have 30-50 non-zero entries)

**Upper triangular approach-
Starting with an identity matrix, choose 30-50 random entries in the upper triangular part to be non-zeros, then do row swaps to make them look random**

(I tried this approach, but the matrices produced turned out to look very skewed to the right.)

Can anyone think up of any other possible approaches to this problem?

Comment: How about the Upper-Triangular approach, but with random row *and column* swaps?

Comment: Will column swaps preserve the invertibility?

Comment: Yes, column swaps preserve invertibility, just like row swaps. The reason is the same.  For the determinant to be zero, the rows or columns must be linearly dependent.  The rank-nullity theorem says these are equivalent.  Swapping columns cannot change the dependence.

Comment: Column swaps are just row swaps of the transpose.

Comment: ah! haha! thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want an invertible matrix $A$ over $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ or over $\mathbb{R}$ ? In the first case, the Blue's method seems to be good. Yet, in the second case, it is not, because $\det(A)=\pm 1$ that is far from random.

EDIT. I assume that you want (although my post does not seem to excite you) an invertible matrix over $\mathbb{Q}$. That follows is a better method than above:

STEP 1. We seek randomly a matrix $B$ as you want and s.t., for every $i$, $B[i,i]=0$. Such a matrix has a non-negligible probability of being singular. Fortunately $C=B+I$ is "almost certainly" invertible; yet $C$ often admits the eigenvalue $1$.

STEP 2. Swap rows and swap columns; then the characteristic polynomial of the obtained matrix $A=PCQ$ is  "almost certainly" irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ and, in particular, $A$ is invertible.

Note that the permutations $P,Q$ must be "dense", otherwise there remain too much $"1"$ on the diagonal and, consequently, your matrix is not random. Write each permutation as a product of $k<n$ transpositions; then the complexity of the calculation of $PC$ (for instance) is the complexity of $n$ swaps, that is $O(n^2)$. On the other hand, I do not know the complexity of the choice of a random permutation.