# Generate "good" invertible binary matrix

Tags: matrices, random-matrices

So what I want to do is generating a (up to 1000 x 1000) invertible matrix over $\mathbb{Z}_2$. I did find some discussion ([How do I generate a sparse invertible 10000 by 10000 binary matrix with 30 to 50 non-zeros per row?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1346638/how-do-i-generate-a-sparse-invertible-10000-by-10000-binary-matrix-with-30-to-50)). However, if you generate from lower triangular matrix and apply permutation, what you get would be a matrix $A$ such that equation $Ax=b$ is easily solvable in $O(n^2)$ steps by substitution.

I want to generate a binary invertible matrix $A$ that is not-necessarily pick from $GL(\mathbb{Z}_2)$ but should be a "good" matrix, in the sense that its corresponding equation is not so easily broken, but easily constructed. By "easy" I mean the total steps required should not be far from $O(n^2)$. Is there a way to generate this kind of matrix?

---edit---

By "not-necessarily pick from $GL(\mathbb{Z}_2)$" I meant you could pick from a smaller class, for example unitary matrices $SU(\mathbb{Z}_2)$. This should be a random pick, though.

Comment: *"So what I want to do is generating a (up to 1000 x 1000) invertible matrix over $\mathbb{Z}_2$... I want to generate a binary invertible matrix $A$ that is not-necessarily pick from $GL(\mathbb{Z}_2)$...".* This is self-contradictory. Every invertible matrix over $\mathbb Z_2$ is by definition a member of $GL(\mathbb Z_2)$.

Comment: @user1551 No, it's not. I meant you could (randomly) pick matrices not from $GL(\mathbb{Z}_2)$ but rather a smaller class, for example, unitary matrices $SU(\mathbb{Z}_2)$.